# Rails: sending an array of hashes from form to server

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my parameters hash, I am trying to achieve something like the following:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"6A14fVUEWQSB83j2BsYKn", "search"=>{"keywords"=>[{"keyword_names"=>"color", "keyword_conditions"=>"is not", "keyword_values"=>"red"}, {"keyword_names"=>"size", "keyword_conditions"=>"is", "keyword_values"=>"3"}] , "assignee_id"=>"", "begin_date"=>"", "end_date"=>""}, "commit"=>"search"}
```

Notice the following:

```
"keywords"=>[{"keyword_names"=>"color", "keyword_conditions"=>"is not", "keyword_values"=>"red"}, {"keyword_names"=>"size", "keyword_conditions"=>"is", "keyword_values"=>"3"}]
```

However, this is what is currently being sent:

```
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"6A14fVUEWQSB83j2BsYKn", "keyword_names"=>["name", "name"], "keyword_conditions"=>["is", "is"], "keyword_values"=>["dan", "john"], "search_add"=>"and", "search"=>{"assignee_id"=>"", "begin_date"=>"", "end_date"=>""}, "commit"=>"search"}
```

Notice keyword_names, keyword_conditions, and keyword_values is not part of the search hash. How can I make it part of the search hash?

This is what I have:

```
  <%= link_to "Add", "#", class: 'add_search'  %>
  <div class="search_container">
    <%= text_field_tag "keyword_names[]" %><%= select_tag "keyword_conditions[]", options_for_select(["is", "is not","is like"]) %><%= text_field_tag "keyword_values[]" %>
  </div>
```

Comment: do you need to wrap your tags in a form with a submit button?

Comment: @Vasseurth I updated my post. Basically I want is the keyword_names, keyword_conditions and keyword_values part of the search hash. And yes it needs to be in form with the rest of search attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following this structure of the params:

```
keywords: 
  [
    { keyword_names: 'color', keyword_conditions: 'is not', keyword_values: 'red' }
  ]
```

You should name your input like this:

```
0..3.each do |index|
  text_field_tag "keywords[#{index}][keyword_names]"
  select_tag "keywords[#{index}][keyword_conditions]", options_for_select(['is', 'is not', 'is like'])
  text_field_tag "keywords[#{index}][keyword_values]"
end
```

Where the `0..3.each do |index|` is a loop defining 4 different sets of 3 inputs for each keyword. So `params[:keywords].size` should return `4`